# linker error with rust when using #![no_std]

Tags: c++, rust, ld, archlinux

I have a little program that I made with Rust, it does literally nothing, but it does not use the std library. It looks like this:

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_panic: &PanicInfo<'_>) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

I also had to add this to my `cargo.toml` otherwise it complains about eh_personality, not sure what it is.

```
[package]
name = "hello-i686"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

But whenever I try to compile it with `cargo run`, I get a `error: linking with cc failed: exit status: 1`.

```
note: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
      /build/glibc/src/glibc/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:103: undefined reference to `main'
      /usr/bin/ld: /build/glibc/src/glibc/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:115: undefined reference to `__libc_start_main'
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

= help: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
= note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
= note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)
```

In pursuit to understand what exactly the problem is, I tried to make a simple hello world program with C++ and link it on my own, by the time I had to link my object files, I realized I have never touched C++ and I have no clue what I'm doing. I found out `crt0.o` is nowhere to be found in my system, I never actually got my C++ program working. I feel like the problem is my development environment, but I've reinstalled base-devel about 3 times now, and I dont have a clue where the issue is. I'm on Artix Linux if that helps at all. When I do use the std library, everything goes off without a hitch.

Comment: Are you following the guide from the [embedonomicon](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/smallest-no-std.html)? You need a different target to compile to, one that's fine with `no_main`, otherwise `cargo run` will try to target your local system, which will expect you to define `main()` *somewhere* to make a runable executable.

Comment: If you're just trying to get Rust running on your local system, then you are way off in the weeds. A simple `src/main.rs` with `fn main() {}` should compile and run just fine (even with `#![no_std]` if you're so inclined)